# Access to Input field Puppetier

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

i have a puppeteer scraper and i have to insert credit card information.
I have no problem to access Cvv and Expire field, but i cannot type in cc number field.

**the input filed in inside iframe  llike this**

```
<iframe src="bla bla bla my url" scrolling="no" name="FrameCCPay" id="FrameCCPay" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100px; height: 18px; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; min-width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

**In frame's document there is this code**

```
<div class="placePan">
   <div class="input-container">
      <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" name="482e7f7b-59aa-3f0d-bde7-8dcf6bcee7a7" class="cleavePan hasError" id="482e7f7b-59aa-3f0d-bde7-8dcf6bcee7a7" maxlength="24" placeholder="Numero Carta" style="display: inline-block;">
      <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="cleavePan" id="482e7f7b-59aa-3f0d-bde7-8dcf6bcee7a7_bin" maxlength="24" placeholder="Numero Carta" style="display: none;">
   </div>
</div>
```

**My Puppetier code**

```
const frame = getFrame(this.page, "FrameCCPay")
await frame.waitForSelector(".placePan input")
await frame.focus('.placePan input')
await frame.type(".placePan input", mynumber)
```

This code is working for the other filed as i said, and the filed ae done in the same way.
The only difference is that cc umber have two input filed with same class (.placePan input) so i think it's here the problem.

I can use TYPE function  in the right input type? how can i exlucde the **.placePan input** that is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

If you think the issue is the hidden input, use a selector with an attribute that is present in the needed input only: `".placePan input[name]"`.

Comment: I can't use name or id, every times this data are different

Comment: @Stefano you do not need the attribute value, just the attribute presence (the selector in the answer just requires the attribute presence).

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't work.
At this point I don't understand what the problem is. I use the same system to compile the next iframe with the cvv field inside and it works correctly for me.

Only that part creates problems